# Update value inside array update_post_meta

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, array, updates

I am trying to change default values inside array in custom field.

But I am getting error **"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array"**  when I try to change the value using following code.

Strangely I use this code in default page template and it works there when I statiscally provide the post id..

but gives error for following code

```
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'oj_publish_campaign',10 ,1);

function oj_publish_campaign($post) {
    global $wpdb;
    $t = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_give_donation_levels', true ); 
    $t[0]["_give_amount"] = 25.00;    // getting error here 
    $t[1]["_give_amount"] = 65.00;
    $t[2]["_give_amount"] = 100.00;
    $t[3]["_give_amount"] = 250.00;
    $t[4]["_give_amount"] = 650.00;    

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_give_donation_levels', $t );
}
```

this is how the initial array for the custom field looks like

[image]

And the strange thing is that it works inside a page-template i.e

if I create a page "Test" and assign it the following template and just load the page , it updates the fields as required

```
/*
Template Name: Test
*/
get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$p = 2234;

$t = give_get_meta( $p, '_give_donation_levels', true );
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($t);echo "</pre>";

$t[0]["_give_amount"] = 25.00;
$t[1]["_give_amount"] = 65.00;
$t[2]["_give_amount"] = 100.00;
$t[3]["_give_amount"] = 250.00;
$t[4]["_give_amount"] = 650.00;

update_post_meta( $p, '_give_donation_levels', $t );        
endwhile; // End of the loop.
get_footer();
```

Can anyone please help me with this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the array you've provided suggests that you're trying to access an incorrect level of the array. Try to replace:

```
$t[0]["_give_amount"] = 25.00;
$t[1]["_give_amount"] = 65.00;
$t[2]["_give_amount"] = 100.00;
$t[3]["_give_amount"] = 250.00;
$t[4]["_give_amount"] = 650.00;
```

with:

```
$t[0][0]["_give_amount"] = 25.00;
$t[0][1]["_give_amount"] = 65.00;
$t[0][2]["_give_amount"] = 100.00;
$t[0][3]["_give_amount"] = 250.00;
$t[0][4]["_give_amount"] = 650.00;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the strange thing is that if I use the same code inside a page template (see updated question) by providing the static page ID then it updates the fields as required..  Infact  when I used your code its not working as expected   for eg: as you can see it added a new key-data in the array https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/30021906?key=e57eefec961a4d25bc06e9eedb8fb100